# Hyperlink doesn't display in an Outlook 2016 with HTML

Tags: html, excel, vba, outlook

I have a macro with Excel VBA that sends an Outlook 2016 email.  Several columns in the data source are used to fill several variables.  One of the variables (MyWedAdd) is a web site.  The website is different for each line in the data source.

In the body of the email, I need to display the hyperlink to the particular website.  The macro works well and sends the Outlook messages exactly like I expect it to; with one little glitch.

The website is not being displayed in the body of the email.  It is blank.  Following is the line of code I'm using to display the website.  I'm fairly certain I have the syntax messed up or the hyperlink to the web site would be displayed

```
"You may pay online at <a href=" & MyWebAdd & "</a> .&ensp;Check or money order payments can also be used."
```

I haven't used HTML very much so this is part of the learning curve for me.  Any suggestions or advice to make this work would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks for your help.  Stay safe....Shaves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the syntax wrong. It must be

```
"You may pay online at <a href=""" & MyWebAdd & """>" & MyWebAdd & "</a> .&ensp;Check or money order payments can also be used."
```

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko......Thank you very much,.  That resolved the issue I was having.  I appreciate your help and sharing your knowleddge with me........